# Unexpected behavior with data.frame(tag=value, ...)

Tags: r, dataframe

According to the documentation for `data.frame(...)`, the `...` argument has the form:

> ```
> ... these arguments are of either the form value or tag = value. 
>     Component names are created based on the tag (if present) or 
>     the deparsed argument itself.
> ```

Consider a data frame with three columns: a, b, c

```
DF <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10], c=rnorm(10))
```

Now consider these three possibilities for creating a new data frame

```
newDF <- data.frame(x=DF$a)
colnames(newDF)        # as expected...
# [1] "x"
newDF <- data.frame(x=DF["a"])
colnames(newDF)        # Huh??
# [1] "a"
newDF <- data.frame(x=DF[["a"]])
colnames(newDF)        # Why is this necessary??
# [1] "x"
```

Looking at the class of each RHS:

```
class(DF$a)
# [1] "integer"
class(DF["a"])
# [1] "data.frame"
class(DF[["a"]])
# [1] "integer"
```

it appears that, if the RHS is a data.frame, then `tag` is overridden by the dimname of `value`.

Also, consider this slightly more complicated example, prompted by [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/21372991/):

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
xtsObject=as.xts(sample_matrix)
head(xtsObject,1)
#                Open     High      Low    Close
# 2007-01-02 50.03978 50.11778 49.95041 50.11778
newDF <- data.frame(x=xtsObject$Open)    # would have expected this to work
colnames(newDF)                          # alas, no...
# [1] "Open"
class(xtsObject$Open)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

**So my question is**: what is the rule when using `data.frame(tag=value,...)`? That is, when can I expect the result to have a column named `"tag"`?

Comment: This is explained in the `Value` section of `?data.frame`.

Comment: Specifically, "For a named or unnamed matrix/list/data frame argument that contains a single column, the column name in the result is the column name in the argument."

Comment: "How the names of the data frame are created is complex, and the rest of this paragraph is only the basic story" AKA... MAGIC.

Comment: @joran - Yes, but I assumed this all applies if `tag` is missing. Otherwise common sense would dictate to use `tag`, no??

Comment: Common sense, maybe, but that's not how I read the documentation, which to me, clearly says that the tag is not used in that case.

Comment: I have to say that I read the documentation as @jlhoward and that I find this behavior unexpected as well.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: If the object supplied to `data.frame` is not named, the result will have the name of the tag.

Let's call the optional arguments to `data.frame` the data.  `data.frame` first creates a list of the data supplied to it.  The function then loops through each element of the list.  If the element of the list has a name, `data.frame` keeps that name.  Technically, it checks to see if `length(names(data[[i]])) > 0` for each element, `i`, of list of the data supplied to the function.  Only if that element has no names, does `data.frame` use `tag` as the name.

Getting back to your example, consider the names of arguments derived from `DF` supplied to `data.frame`:

```
names(DF$a)
# NULL
names(DF['a'])
# [1] "a"
names(DF[['a']])
# NULL
```

Notice that in the first and third case, `names(...)` is `NULL`.  That is why `data.frame(x = DF$a)` and `data.frame(x = DF[['a']])` had the expected name: `x`.

For the more complicated `xts` object, however, notice that the resulting object from the subset operation with `$` has a name:

```
names(xtsObject$Open)
#"Open"
names(xtsObject[, 'Open'])
#"Open"
```

Therefore, in either case the data frame created with either `data.frame(x=xtsObject[, 'Open'])` or `data.frame(x=xtsObject$Open)` will have the name `Open`.

Here is the relevant code where the names are set in `data.frame`.  Note that `x` is `list(...)` where the `...` is the data.

```
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  xi <- if (is.character(x[[i]]) || is.list(x[[i]])) 
    as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors)
  else as.data.frame(x[[i]], optional = TRUE)
  nrows[i] <- .row_names_info(xi)
  ncols[i] <- length(xi)
  namesi <- names(xi)
  if (ncols[i] > 1L) {
    if (length(namesi) == 0L) 
      namesi <- seq_len(ncols[i])
    if (no.vn[i]) 
      vnames[[i]] <- namesi
    else vnames[[i]] <- paste(vnames[[i]], namesi, sep = ".")
  }
  else {
    if (length(namesi)) 
      vnames[[i]] <- namesi
    else if (no.vn[[i]]) {
      tmpname <- deparse(object[[i]])[1L]
      if (substr(tmpname, 1L, 2L) == "I(") {
        ntmpn <- nchar(tmpname, "c")
        if (substr(tmpname, ntmpn, ntmpn) == ")") 
          tmpname <- substr(tmpname, 3L, ntmpn - 1L)
        }
      vnames[[i]] <- tmpname
    }
  }
  if (mirn && nrows[i] > 0L) {
    rowsi <- attr(xi, "row.names")
    nc <- nchar(rowsi, allowNA = FALSE)
    nc <- nc[!is.na(nc)]
    if (length(nc) && any(nc)) 
      row.names <- data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, 
                                  i)
  }
  nrows[i] <- abs(nrows[i])
  vlist[[i]] <- xi
}
```